# Instagram API, pending review

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api

I really need 'Instagram login' feature, but I'm still not getting the basic permission in the existing Instagram API.

My Instagram app did not received the app review for more than a month. (still pending review..) Is there any possibility that Instagram will start the app review again? When will it be normalized?

Comment: Did you get an approval from Instagram?

Comment: Any update?  We're still pending, but it's only been a couple of weeks.

Comment: We are also waiting for a reply. Pending review for weeks now. No contact, no info, no help.